# How to define custom tag for JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I follow the book servlet-jsp tutorial and write the following code:
src/MyFirstTag.java

```
public class MyFirstTag implements SimpleTag {
    JspContext jspContext;

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doTag");
        jspContext.getOut().print("This is my first tag.");
    }


    @Override
    public void setJspContext(JspContext jspContext) {
        System.out.println("setJspContext");
        this.jspContext = jspContext;
    }

}
```

and register the tag /web/WEB-INF/mytags.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <description>
        Simple tag examples
    </description>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>example</short-name>
    <tag>
        <name>firstTag</name>
        <tag-class>MyFirstTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

And finally the JSP file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/mytags.tld" prefix="easy"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<easy:firstTag></easy:firstTag>
</body>
</html>
```

But it keeps telling me

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tagtest_jsp

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tagtest_jsp
```

Why the custom tag cannot be found? I thinks the `taglib uri="/WEB-INF/mytags.tld"` and the `<tag-class>MyFirstTag</tag-class>` should give the path of the java class.

Comment: are you getting another error when deploying your webapp?

Comment: I found that when I change the 'implements SimpleTag' to 'extends TagSupport', then the code can work. I don't know why.